# Full Project Swift Compile Error Immediately After Successful Run with a New Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I ran my Swift 4.2 project in the simulator successfully. When I stopped the simulator, changed some small code, and began again, the entire project exploded. I reverted back the small code change. But the entire project still is broken.

Not from the code change, as my code change was setting a bool to true, but it appears as if something fundamental has broken.

Errors like:

1. Use of undeclared type 'ViewController'
2. Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'view' Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegue'
3. Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'present'
4. 'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class
5. Method does not override any method from its superclass
6. Value of type 'ViewController' has no member
   'setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate'
7. Protocol requires property 'hash' with type 'Int'; do you want to add the stub?

I have commented out just about every class.

I even started a completely new project, imported my classes, ran it successfully, stopped the simulator and immediately started again and the exact same thing happened.

I am unsure at why this is happening. Anyone have any suggestions? At this point I don't even know what to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the use of undeclared type `ViewController` error because there is no type called `ViewController`. It should be `UIViewController`.

Many of the other errors depend on this very fact - Since `ViewController` is not a type within the Cocoa Touch Framework, the class is non-existent and thus does not have any of those properties that you et in the other errors.

Of course, without seeing any of your code it is hard to locate the culprit, but the fact that you are declaring your `viewController` as being of type `ViewController` instead of `UIViewController` is probably a big part of it.

Comment: That makes since and I replaced the `UI` part. But.... how did it happen in the first place?  Why did it compile and run and then drop the UI part?

Comment: Not really sure. I am surprised that it worked in the first place. It may be cause of some assumptions that the compiler is making when the project is first run. Is it working as expected now?

Comment: Yes, when I re-added `UI` to all my ViewController classes, it started working again.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! If you want to mark this answer as approved it would help me out a lot as I am trying to build some reputation on StackOverflow. Cheers!

Comment: Yes. I'll do that as soon as the time limit restriction is lifted.

Comment: Thanks! Cheers bud